# The region bounded by $x+y=4$ and $x=5-(y-1)^2$ is rotated about the $x$-axis. What is the volume of the resulting solid?

Tags: calculus

I'm so burned out from trying to figure this out. Anyways, here it is:

> Find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by the given curves about the specified axis.
>   $$x+y=4, \qquad x=5-(y-1)^2, \qquad x\text{-axis}$$

My work is shown in these images:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE. what have you done so far ?

Comment: If you don't know MathJax, please learn some basics from [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/578155). Also, if you start by showing your thoughts and/or attempts for your question it will be much easier for us to help you. If you don't put those, I am afraid this question might get closed.

Comment: I could show you pictures of multiple notebook pages of attempts. I've spent about 3 hours on this one question with no avail. At this point I'm just looking for someone to setup the integral for me so I can see what they did. Nothing I found on the internet has helped. I couldn't even tell what I've done. I've done it all.

Comment: pleas post your attempts then

Comment: @DecapitatedRainbow Yes, please show us everything that you have tried. You may upload the pics but I would rather suggest you to learn about MathJax from the above link and write everything down instead of posting an image.

Comment: Well, I'm no expert (or in) Calculus, but I suggest finding the piece of one part and "cutting" off pieces that are not inside

Comment: @DecapitatedRainbow Just to be clear .. MSE is not a place to post homework or test questions.

Comment: I will learn MathJax, but for right now, I would like to get this problem done before I try spending my time on other things. You guys/gals are my last hope. I get most of this volume stuff, but this one stumps me. And this isn't  just me being lazy asking for someone to do my homework. This is me asking for help from folks who can get me in the right direction. I have tried to do this problem.

Comment: I wasn't supposed to post an answer? Oops.

Comment: Can you sketch the area you want to revolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as no one wanted to help me and instead wanted me to learn MathJax or tell me what I already knew. I ended up having to just do more testing for hours. And finally got the answer. So here it is. The two line's are bounded by, $x=1,4$ and $y=0,3$. Using the Cylindrical Shell Method in terms of y: $$\int_{y=0}^{3} 2\pi y(5-(y-1)^2-(4-y))dy$$ With this I was able to find the correct answer: $$\frac{27\pi}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Well, the $x+y=4$ will just give a cone. You may find it easier just to subtract off its volume, then do the calculation with discs rather than circles.

For volumes of revolution find the radius as a function of $x$, convert to an area, then integrate over the limits (between intersection points).

In full area disc $= \pi (y^2 _2- y^2_1) = \pi \left((6-x+2\sqrt{5-x}) - (4-x)^2\right).$

That should get you started.

Comment: $x+y=4$ is not a cone; it's a line, $y=-x+4$.

Comment: Rotated around the x axis it is

Comment: Even if this was the right way to do this, it would need to be in terms of y

Comment: You do it for y if you integrate cylinders and x if you integrate discs.